# Array to json code conversion - wrong format

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to send back an array as json to my jquery form but the format is not how it should

I am using this code here

```
$this->options['tost'] => array (
     $this->options['param'] => $this->get_file_objects())
```

it should give me this format

```
{"tost":["param":[{"name":"2013-12-12_171356 (12).png","size":94541]]}
```

but it's sending this format

```
{"tost":{"param":[{"name":"2013-12-12_171356 (12).png","size":94541]}}
```

You can see that what I am getting here is curly bracket `{` after the `{"tost":` I need to get square bracket there

Comment: an array has never a key, that is an object, is all about a object notation

Comment: The format you want is not valid JSON

Comment: ["param":[{"name":"2013-12-12_171356 (12).png","size":94541]] //array cannot have a key, you can use an array to store an object like this: [{"param":[{"name":"2013-12-12_171356 (12).png","size":94541]}]

Comment: @h2ooooooo what is he trying to get? JSON or PSON? ;)

Comment: Why do you want a `[` there?  What are you doing with this JSON?  Where are you trying to use it?  Your desired format is not valid JSON.  JSON can only have numeric arrays and objects, it *cannot* have associative arrays.

Comment: You are right this is not how it should be done. I found a different solution. Thanks I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is this:

```
$this->options['tost'][] => array (
 $this->options['param'] => $this->get_file_objects())
```

Notice the `[]` after the `$this->options['tost']`, that tells the JSON encoder that you're building an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest it in another level of array() then.

{ means there's an associative key.
[ means there is not.

for example

```
$this->options['tost'] => array ( array(
     $this->options['param'] => $this->get_file_objects()) )
```